# Como colocar uma classe dentro de um JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Alguém sabe como colocar uma classe dentro de um arquivo JSON? Eu preciso guardar uma classe dentro de um arquivo JSON, porém, ele retorna que esse arquivo não é serializável. Alguém sabe como eu posso colocar essa classe dentro do arquivo, pra depois usar?
Ex:

```
import json
class Teste:
    pass
dict = {'Class': Teste}
json.dumps(dict)
```

Comment: OBs: (python 3.6)

Comment: Já tentou o [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)?

Comment: O que seria isto?

Comment: Um pacote do Python. Acesse o link e veja.

Comment: Hmm, entendi, obrigado.

Comment: Para conseguir responder, você terá que [edit] a pergunta e adicionar um [mcve].

Comment: No caso, se for mandatorio o uso de json, pode-se usar tb o [jsonpickle.](http://jsonpickle.github.io/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Jsonpickle:](http://jsonpickle.github.io/)

**Criando a classe:**

```
import jsonpickle
class Foo():
    def test(self):
        return 'bar'
foo = Foo()
```

**Convertendo o obejto em uma string JSON:**

```
jfoo = jsonpickle.encode(foo)
```

**Recriando o objeto python a partir da string JSON:**

```
foo2 = jsonpickle.decode(jfoo)
```

**Executando o objeto (a classe) recriado:**

```
foo2.test()
'bar'
```

[Clique aqui para a documentação.](http://jsonpickle.github.io/)

---

### [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Se não for obrigado a usar json, temos a opção do pickle (mais seguro) no python:

**Criando a classe:**

```
import pickle
class Foo():
    def test(self):
        return 'bar'
```

**Serializando:**

```
foo = Foo()
with open('foo.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(foo, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

**Lendo do disco para a memoria (Desserializando):**

```
with open('foo.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    foo2 = pickle.load(f)
```

**Executando a classe desserializada:**

```
foo2.test()
'bar'
```

[Clique aqui para a documentação.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, um lapso.